# Shadow DOM in a button

Tags: html, dom, shadow-dom

There's a working JS Fiddle that demonstrates [Shadow DOM](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/shadow/index.html) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dglazkov/eQSZd/). (**Note:** There's some setup required to get this to work. I'm on Google Chrome Version 20.0.1132.47 beta with the "Shadow DOM" experiment enabled via `chrome://flags`)

I created a revision of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eQSZd/3/) that uses a `button` instead of a `span`, and it doesn't work. It throws an:

```
Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3
```

Any idea why you can add Shadow DOM to a `span` but not a `button`?

Comment: If someone with 1500+ reputation could create a new tag called `shadow-dom` and add it to this, I think that would be appropriate.

Comment: I saw your comment after I had added it! Not sure on the answer though.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can subscribe to that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current implementation in WebKit.

Early on in the implementation, an element could have at most one shadow root attached to it. Because some elements used Shadow DOM internally (such as video) or planned to (such as input elements) there's [a hard-coded restriction](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search?q=allowsAuthorShadowRoot&origq=allowsAuthorShadowRoot&btnG=Search%20Trunk) that disallows creating an author shadow root for these elements.

You can track the status of the implementation of author Shadow DOM for button elements in [WebKit bug 91486.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91486)

Comment: Related newbie question: The best way to 'track the status' of a bug in BugZilla is to add myself to the CC List, right?

Comment: @CletusW Yep, creating a WebKit Bugzilla account and adding yourself to the CC list is the way to track the status of a WebKit bug.